# probability of choose team

Tags: probability

There are 10 girl and 5 boy. If we choose a 5 of them randomly, whats the probability of that 5 consists 2 boy and 3 girl? 
 here is my solution: 
 `(2choose from 5)x(3choose from 10) over (5 choose from 15)= 400 over 1001`

> (2choose from 5)=10
>   
> (3choose from 10)=120
> (3choose from 10)=3003

but i dont feel like its true. Its almost `0.4` probability (feel like it should be lower than this) and i calculated in different way(not formal way which is teacher wont accept) and answer became

> 40 over 1001

. 
 my method is wrong or why is this happening ?

Comment: What was your other way of calculating it?

Comment: 5/15 * 4/14 * 10/13 * 9/12 * 8/11 = 40/1001 <br> if u understand

Comment: @thanasissdr which one is correct ? and why?

Comment: @Andy $p=\displaystyle \dfrac{\binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{10}{3}}{\binom{15}{5}}=\dfrac{400}{1001}$


$\binom{5}{2}$: the ways we can choose the boys

$\binom{10}{3}$: the ways we can choose the girls

Comment: @Andy This answer $\dfrac{5}{15}\cdot \dfrac{4}{14}\cdot\dfrac{10}{13}\cdot\dfrac{9}{12}\cdot\dfrac{8}{11}$  covers only the case BBGGG.. But we want all combinations (e.g. GGBGB).

The modified answer of yours would be true: $\dfrac{5}{15}\cdot \dfrac{4}{14}\cdot\dfrac{10}{13}\cdot\dfrac{9}{12}\cdot\dfrac{8}{11}\mathbf {\cdot \dfrac{5!}{2! \cdot 3!}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer--calculated in the prescribed way--is correct.

Your "informal" answer is incorrect, because it assumes that the first two choices are boys and the last three choices are girls. Do you see where that (hidden) assumption is made?

Comment: you mean that i can choose girls first ?

Comment: Yes. Or GGBGB. Or GBGBG. Or GBBGG. Or any arrangement of three girls and two boys. There are in fact *ten* different ways to do this, all equally likely. Hence, by specifying an order, you have come up with an answer that is $\frac1{10}$ of the correct answer.